# How do you handle errors for Facebook SDK functions like FB.getLoginStatus()?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Under certain circumstances, using functions like `FB.getLoginStatus()` will cause console errors such as:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given...

The problem is that if an error like this occurs, the callback to the function never gets called. Is there any way to handle errors of this kind? `try/catch` doesn't work, and the function doesn't return anything directly. I also want to avoid a timeout hack if possible.

There is nothing in the docs explaining how to deal with errors of this kind either: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

**Note: I am not trying to solve the error above, I am trying to figure out to handle it**

Answer (score 0):

That error only happens if your App is not configured correctly, so you don´t need to handle it in your code, you just need to make sure to add a platform with the correct URL in the App settings (Website, Page Tab, Canvas App, ...).

Everything else can be handled in the callback response, you don´t need any specific error handling for that, just the code from the Facebook docs. If the settings are correct, there WILL be a response. Meaning: error handling can be done by checking the content of "response".

Comment: This question is not about the error above, but all errors!

Comment: it really depends on what errors you want to handle. you mentioned a specific one, and that´s not something you need to handle, that´s just a setting.

Comment: Well, you still may want to handle the error above anyway. What if you want to use the function above, but are in a dev environment, so you want to handle the error for localhost?

Comment: why would anyone want to handle that error if it is just a setting issue? for a dev environment, you can use test apps - or add another platform with localhost.

Comment: It will only let you add a single platform, so you would have to use another app, which is annoying. Besides, if you cannot handle these errors, it is horrible design on facebooks behalf.

Comment: no, you CAN add another platform for testing, just use a page app or canvas app for that. it only matters that the domain is in there.

Comment: and it is not really an error you should check for, as i said. it is a setting you have to do anyway, or the facebook stuff will not work at all. meaning, that error will never happen for other users - assuming you test your website before going live ;)